# How to log values of variables during a sql script execution

Tags: sql, db2

I have a complex sql script which I am running using `db2 +v -txf sqls/connection.sql` This script is part of a unix service which is running lot of other scripts as well. The script is querying a temporary session table so I cannot run the script manually (since the table is gone by that time). I want to be able to run the script as part of the service but would like to log the values of variables being calculated in the sql file. For eg: The sql script as the following line `timestampdiff(1, char(max(END_TS) - min(START_TS))) as ELAPSED_TIME,` I would like to know the values of `END_TS` and `START_TS`.

What I have tried:
I tried adding -v to the the db2 command and it printed the entire sql being executed but not the exact values.

Answer (score 0):

If the Db2-server runs on Linux/unix/windows, you can use `set serveroutput on;` along with  `call dbms_output.PUT_LINE('......');`  which lets you see what you logged as output **when the script ends**.

[dbms_output.put_line docs.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dom-put-line-procedure-put-complete-line-in-message-buffer#r0053539.dita)

The [dbms_output](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=modules-dbms-output-module) module contains other useful services, and people familiar with Oracle will recognize it.

If the Db2-server runs on a Z/OS or i-series you should tag your question as db2-zos or db2-400 , because the answer can depend on the platform.